# django form not posting, but other form on page does?

Tags: python, django

I have two forms on a page. The first form properly sends a POST request to my view but the second form sends a GET (I need it to also send a POST). I've made this mistake before and this time I made sure that the button is set to "submit", but for some reason it still sends a GET.

form 1 (working as intended):

```
<form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row form-row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="start_date">Start</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" data-flatpickr data-alt-input="true" data-date-format="Y-m-d" name="start_date" data-enable-time="true">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="end_date">End</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" data-flatpickr data-alt-input="true" data-date-format="Y-m-d" name="end_date" data-enable-time="true">                   
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <input type="hidden" name="eventtype" value="availability">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save changes</button>
              </form>
```

form 2 (sends a GET but I want this to POST):

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% if form.errors %}{{form.errors}}{% endif %}
  <input type="hidden" name="pk" value="{{ i.id }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="eventtype" value="invite">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def createevent(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        <<code>>
    else:
        try:
            eventtype = request.POST.get('eventtype', None)
            print(eventtype)
            if eventtype == "availability":
                form = EventForm(request.POST)
                newEvent = form.save(commit=False)
                newEvent.mentor_user = request.user
                newEvent.requester_user = None
                newEvent.notes = None
                newEvent.save()
            elif eventtype == "invite":
                form = EventForm(request.POST)
                updatedEvent = form.save(commit=False)
                updatedEvent.isConfirmed = True
                updatedEvent.save()
            return redirect('createevent')
        except ValueError:
            print(form.errors)
            return render(request, 'events/createevent.html', {'form':EventForm(), 'error':'There was an error. Please make sure you entered everything correctly!'})
```

urls.py

```
# Events
path('events/create', views.createevent, name='createevent'),
# path('calendar/<slug:slug>', views.viewevent, name='viewevent'),
path('events/<int:pk>/edit', views.updateevent, name='updateevent'),
```

console output for form 1 and form 2:

```
"GET /events/create?csrfmiddlewaretoken=<<redacted>>&pk=2&eventtype=invite HTTP/1.1" 200 25560


"POST /events/create?csrfmiddlewaretoken=<<redacted>>&pk=2&eventtype=invite HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

Comment: Looks like both forms are being submitted to the same url.. try adding ***action= url path to the view***

Comment: I tried `action="{% url 'createevent' %}">` but that didn't seem to do anything

Comment: So you are using same view for creating and updating, i guess!! But you are using different url paths.. I suggest you to create separate views for both the action and set action path for both the forms!!

Answer (score 0):

Set the action of form to your url path.
Look at this:

```
<form name="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'your_url_name' %}">
```

Comment: I added `action="{% url 'createevent' %}">` but the outcome is still the same. Not sure why that didn't work

Comment: try to put the different names for forms.

Comment: ```<form name="form1"```
and
```<form name="form2"```

Comment: May your 'eventtype' input isn't be 'invite'.
Are you sure is it 'Invite'?
Please try to remove ```{% if form.errors %}{{form.errors}}{% endif %}``` from your code snippet.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't do anything either. the invite value should be fine, I'm able to pass in hidden values to the view in the first form

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being the form was wrapped in another form tag further up in the template code. When I clicked the Submit button, the Submit button was firing on the first form and not the second. Just a bad copy/paste.